# In azure data factory copy activity ,fault tolerance is not applicable to check constraint

Tags: azure, stored-procedures, fault-tolerance, azure-data-factory

I want to copy data from one table to another in azure data factory using copy activity.In source there are no constraints but on sink I have check constraint on age column  --->  check(age>=18). What I have observed is,if while copy activity runs to copy data from source to sink if even one record fails due to check constraint the entire copy activity fails and it will not copy any row to sink even though i have given option to skip and log error records.

Please give me solution to load all good records to sink table and all records that fail due to check constraint should be skipped and logged somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Try the `Skip and log incompatible rows` option for `Fault Tolerance`

[image]

Comment: skip and log wont work for check constraint failure..if any rows fails due to check constraint then entire copy activity will fail even if we give skip and log